# Dois-je dire « hier soir » ou « ce matin » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, oral, indications-de-temps

Admettons que j'ai veillé tard pour lire un livre (par exemple 3h du matin).

1. Lorsque je relate le fait le même jour à 10h, dois-je dire :

   > J'ai lu un livre jusqu'à 3h hier soir

   ou

   > J'ai lu un livre jusqu'à 3h ce matin

   Les deux formules sont-elles correctes ? Personnellement, j'aurais tendance à employer la première formule même si à 3h, on est le matin mais pourquoi ?
2. De plus, est-ce que cela dépend du fait de passer une nuit entre 3h et 10h ou pas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les 2 se comprennent, mais de par mon expérience il est plus courant de situer la période précédent le sommeil par le soir. Comme si ce n'était pas l'heure qui déterminait le changement de jour, mais le sommeil. Ainsi, il sera plus courant d'entendre

> Hier soir, je me suis couché à 3h

que

> Ce matin, je me suis couché à 3h

Tout simplement parce qu'habituellement, on ne se couche pas le matin.

Comment: On peut même préciser: "Hier, je me suis couché à 3h du matin"

Comment: @rds: Et pourtant, c'était ce matin.

Answer (score 2):

> Hier soir, je me suis couché à trois heures.

Signifie que c'est le soir, donc la veille, que la décision de se coucher a été prise, et donc que se coucher à trois heures est exceptionnel, inhabituel.

> Ce matin, je me suis couché à trois heures.

Sous-entendu, d'habitude je me couche à cinq heures, à la sortie de mon travail de nuit par exemple, ou parce que je suis en voyage et qu'il y a eu des imprévus.

> Cette nuit, j'ai dévoré le dernier roman à la mode ; je l'ai fini à trois heures ce matin.

Là, on insiste sur l'exception.

Answer (score 1):

Je n'ai pas de référence à fournir, sinon le dictionnaire, qui précise qu'hier est le jour précédent celui où l'on se trouve, et mon "instinct" de locuteur natif.  Je dirais cela dépend si on met l'accent sur le début de l'action ou la fin et si elle continue on non:

> J'ai lu un livre hier, je l'ai fini à 3 h **du** matin.

L'action est continue, le sous-entendu suivant "du" est que l'on parle du matin qui est immédiatement à la suite de la nuit où est commencée l'action. Donc, en fin de compte, je dirais:

> J'ai lu un livre jusqu'à 3h du matin

Comment: Ca ne répond pas précisémment à mes questions.

Answer (score 1):

Si il est clairement plus courant (et généralement mieux compris) de parler du "soir" pour les dernières choses qu'on a faites avant de se coucher (et le plus souvent de dormir), cette réponse n'est malheureusement pas bonne *sticto sensus*.

1. il ne s'agit pas vraiment du soir mais déjà de la nuit.
2. il ne s'agit pas du tout d'hier mais bien d'aujourd'hui.

Celà dit tout la première formule (bien qu'inexacte) étant plus répandue, il est communément admis qu'elle sera la meilleure.

L'important là est de savoir si l'on souhaite s'adresser à des collègues à une pause clope ou à un robot.

En ce qui me concerne je suis plus familier de la première situation que de la seconde.